# What publicly accessible vantage points exist in Portland, Oregon?

Tags: photography, vantage-points, portland

Any publicly accessible tall buildings that are good for views & photography in Portland, Oregon?

Or is the Aerial tram a better bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Portland City Grill](http://portlandcitygrill.com) is a restaurant at the top of the U.S. Bancorp Tower and was voted "Best View" in 2003 by USA Today.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the [Pittock Mansion](http://pittockmansion.org/) for a stunning view over Portland.

Comment: Agreed! My family and I just visited there, and the view (as well as the interior) of Pittock Mansion was wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the kind of views you want, you might find that [Washington Park](http://www.portlandoregon.gov/parks/finder/index.cfm?&propertyid=841&action=viewpark) offers what you need. It's set on hills just above the city, but with good public transport links to get there (MAX and Bus).

You need to be over on the Rose Garden side of the park to see the city. If it isn't the view you wanted, it's not the end of the world, as you're in the lovely Rose Garden at the time!

(You'll need the Rose Garden, rather than the Japanese Garden, as the latter has lots of trees on the entrance side which faces the city, with post of the gardens sunken down. Lovely, but not right for seeing the city)

Answer (score 1):

The upper area of the sanctuary at [The Grotto](https://thegrotto.org/) also has a great view!

> If magnificent views are what you are after, the upper area of the
> sanctuary is where you want to be. From a birds-eye view of Portland
> to the natural beauty of the setting, the upper area is a place that
> must be seen to be believed. On a clear day several of the area's
> mountains are visible and you can even catch a glimpse of Mt. St.
> Helens. The upper level can be reached by trails or by elevator for
> those who might not be able to make the trip on foot. Most of the
> trails are paved and very even - so the risk of injury for hikers and
> walkers is very slight.

https://www.oregon.com/attractions/grotto